# Cube with smooth structure

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

My question is:

> Can the cube $C=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}; \max\{|x_{i}|; 1\leq i \leq n\} = 1\}$ be endowed with a smooth differentiable structure? If not, how can I justify that?

I've been trying to prove that it is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but I didn't succeed. I also tried to find a way to see that it is not true (once I'm in doubt), but I couldn't either.

Thanks

Comment: Of course your definition means the boundary of the cube.

Comment: Yes, as I defined there. He calls the boundary as the cube, thats why I put the definition.

Comment: The answer is yes, for trivial reasons. You probably meant to require the differentiable manifold structure to agree with the topology $C$ gets as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$. You get a downvote from me for this,

Comment: The question was exactly like that. And from what I know by now, it is not a trivial question. You should know that not everyone that ask something here have the same background, so what is so simple to one it is not to others. You should think carefully next time.

Comment: It is a trivial question as you have stated it and it is important that you should understand that. However, please accept my apologies for criticising with a downvote, which, I agree was a bit harsh. (If you edit the question a bit, I'll upvote.) My point was that if you ask "can some set $X$ be equipped with some structure that satisfies blah, blah, blah", then the answer depends only on the cardinality of $X$ and the properties "blah,blah, blah".

Answer (score 4):

Nice question. The answer is that it can be endowed with a smooth differentiable structure, but it does not naturally inherit one from $\mathbb{R}^n$. To give it a differentiable structure, you could for example pick a homeomorphism from the cube to a sphere, and use it to endow the cube with a differentiable structure.

Comment: I don't see how a homeomorphism is enough to endow a smooth differentiable structure.  A diffeomorphism, yes -- But I don;t think there is a diffeomorphism between the surfaces of a cube and a sphere.  I could be wrong, there.

Comment: @MarkFischler if $X$ and $Y$ are topological manifolds that are homeomorphic, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a smooth structure on $Y$, then the pullback of $\mathcal{A}$ along the homeomorphism is a smooth structure on $X$. Note also that it doesn't make sense tospeak of a diffeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ if one has a smooth structure on $Y$ but not on $X$.

Comment: @MarkFischler (the question asks if the surface of the cube can be given a smooth structure, and the answer is yes -- however, it's true that the embedding of the cube into $\mathbb{R}^n$ is *not* smooth with respect to this structure.)

Comment: That was going to be my next question, by the way, haha... Isn't the inclusion map even an immersion with this smooth structure?